# ¿Como se instancia directamente un array de dos dimensiones dandole parametros en el new?

Tags: c#, array, objeto

En el caso de ser un array de una sola dimensión seria;

```
    new Vectores().ComprobarMenor(new int[] { 2, 4, 66, 6, 3, 7, 2, 7, 2, 13, 6 ,0});
```

¿Pero si son dos dimensiones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[,] array = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

Comment: por añadir informacion, creo que array[0,0] seria 1, array[0,1] seria 2.. array[1,0] seria 4, array [1,1] seria 5

Comment: Y si necesito que el array sea de 3 x 4? Inicianizandolos de esa manera me obliga a poner la segunda dimensión del mismo tamaño que la primera...

Comment: Un 3 x 4 sería `int[,] array = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9 , 10, 11, 12 }};` Lo que te obliga es a que todas las filas tengan la misma cantidad de elementos, pero puedes tener diferente cantidad de filas que columnas.